# How can I start a MMC Agent?

Tags: mule

I have a stand alone **Mule Community Edition** instance running an app, which I'd like to view in the Mule Management Console.

I've downloaded the MMC Trial and successfully connected to the trial's Enterprise Mule instance. When trying to add a new server on MMC, connecting to my Community Edition instance, it displays an error with Connection Refused.

Some Googling shows that it I should start the *MMC Agent* on that server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to connect to MMC, you need a agent running along your esb server, which is the one that sends data to MMC and receives commands such as stop/restart/etc.
ESB EE runtime comes in 2 flavors: with or without the MMC agent included. In the case is not included, you can add it later as an addon. But you can't add it to a Community Edition (CE).
You need the EE version, that is why the mmc trial version comes with the ee runtime trial version.
So, in the case you want to test your application running along with the MMC, you have to deploy it in the Mule EE instance (you can deploy the application from MMC).

Answer (score 0):

In the first place I am not sure if Mule MMC agent working with Community Edition. As per MuleSoft MMC is an enterprise only feature.

For running an MMC Agent.

First download an MMC agent from MuleSoft (Mule Enterprise Trail will provide you with MMC and MMC Agent)

Then copy the MMC agnet zip file to Mule standalone server apps folder.

Then start Mule standalon server.

Mule starts and shows that MMC agent is deployed and running.

Then your MMC should be able to detect the server instance.

Refer to the following link for more details on MMC

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+the+Trial+Version+of+MMC

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the MMC trial, but can only find the mmc-agent APIs.
`~/Development/mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.1/mmc-3.5.1  ᐅ find . -iname "*mmc*" | grep agent`
`./apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/mmc-3.5.1/WEB-INF/lib/mmc-agent-api-3.5.1.jar`
`./apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/mmc-3.5.1/WEB-INF/lib/mmc-agent-common-api-3.3.1.jar`
`./apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/mmc-3.5.1/WEB-INF/lib/mmc-agent-mule2-api-3.3.1.jar`
I can also only find JARs related to the mmc-agent, so ZIPs. Where would I be able to get a zip?

Comment: if you are using Mule 3.5.1 then get an Enterprise edition trail. From Mule 3.4 MMC Agent comes bundled with Mule Enterprise Edition server.